# Saving source code formatting to TXT file

Tags: c#, webclient, string-formatting

I am trying to extract the source code from a webpage and save it to a text file. However, I want to keep the formatting of the source code.

My code is below.

```
// this block fetches the source code from the URL entered.
        private void buttonFetch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                string s = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.ebay.com");

                Clipboard.SetText(s, TextDataFormat.Text);

                string[] lines = { s };
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\user\Dropbox\Personal Projects\WriteLines.txt", lines);

                MessageBox.Show(s.ToString(), "Source code",
                MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            }
        }
```

I would like the text file to show the source code as it is formatted in the Messagebox.

Messagebox screenshot:
[image]

Text file screenshot:
[image]

How would I go about getting the text document's formatting to be the same as in the Messagebox?

Comment: Open it with notepad++ and it should work.
For some strange reason notepad wants to be different in how it reads new lines http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ If this works and is okay for you, I'll add it as an answer, otherwise I'll just keep it here in the comments

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comment, but I'll add just a note.  If you open it in Notepad++, N++ will detect the line endings and display the file nicely for you.  In Notepad++ you can go into the menu and change the Line Endings to Windows.  If you then re-save it and open it in Notepad itself, it will look correctly.  The problem is that the base Notepad doesn't understand different line endings.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the string you're downloading has LF-only line endings. The Windows standard is CRLF line endings. Windows Notepad is notoriously adamant about supporting *only* CRLF line endings. Other editors, including Visual Studio, correctly handle the LF-only versions.

You can convert the text to CRLF line endings easily enough:

```
string s = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.ebay.com");
string fixedString = s.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("filename", fixedString);
MessageBox.Show(fixedString, "Source code",
            MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
```

Note also that it is not necessary to call `ToString` on a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string[] lines = s.Split('\n');
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\user\Dropbox\Personal Projects\WriteLines.txt", lines);
```